# Why isn't my div swap working?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I need a div to slide up when another slides down.

**Example:**

When Home button is clicked a div, we'll call it `box_Home`, slides down. When Games button is clicked, `box_Home` should slide up and then `box_Games` should slide down. What's happening is that they are overlapping instead of swapping out.

http://jsfiddle.net/M8UgQ/15/

```
var open = $('.open'),
    a = $('ul').find('a');

console.log(a.hasClass('active'));

open.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        speed = 500;

    var link_id = $this.attr('id');
    var box_id = '#box_' + link_id;

    console.log(box_id);
    if($this.hasClass('active') === true) {
        $this.removeClass('active');
        $(box_id).slideUp(speed);
    } else if(a.hasClass('active') === false) {
        $this.addClass('active');
        $(box_id).slideDown(speed);
    } else {
        a.removeClass('active')
        $(box_id).slideUp(speed);

        $this.addClass('active');
        $(box_id).delay(speed).slideDown(speed);
    }
});
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Can you please simplify you problem as it's hard to figure out what is it that you are trying to accomplish. Your code logic doesn't reflect what you are explaining in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this
http://jsfiddle.net/rWrJ9/1/

the main idea is...

if the element clicked is `active`, remove it, otherwise: **1.** find (if any) already `active` elements (using `$('.active')`) and use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to make them inactive and slide them up, and **2.** make the element clicked `active`.

I also removed the unneeded variable `a`

**IMPORTANT:** the `this` inside the `map()` function is different from the `this` (or rather, `$this` as you called it) outside the `map()` function

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying you have two buttons `id="Home" class="open"` and `id="Game" class="open"`, and two divs `id="box_Home"` and `id="box_Game"`. If so, you add `class="box"` to box_Home and box_Game and do something like this:

```
$('.open').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    var link_id = $this.attr('id');
    var box_id = '#box_' + link_id;

    $('.box').slideUp();
    $(box_id).slideDown();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this fiddle i hope you need thing to implement
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8UgQ/17/)

in the if else statement you are doing a mistake

```
else if(a.hasClass('active') === false) {
```

replace it with

```
else if($this.hasClass('active') === false) {
```